# How is Asymptotic Complexity Derived for Recursive Functions

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, binary-search, theory, asymptotic-complexity

*I haven't found a general answer to this on the website*

### For Example

If I have some algorithm; say Binary Search how do I derive (mathematically show) its complexity is `O(log(n))`.

But more generally **how do I derive the asymptotic complexity of any recursive algorithm?**

Comment: There is no general answer. Every calculation depends on the nature of the algorithm. The only "general" way to do so would be to experimentally measure the computation time for a range of different inputs, and fit the data to known existing functions.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog okay, what about the binary search example?

Comment: I can't post an answer for just an example. But you can construct a *recurrence relation* for most recursive algorithms. For binary search, each time the search space narrows down by 50%, so the relation function is `T(n) = T(n/2) + C`. If you solve this you should get `O(log n)`

Comment: @meowgoesthedog ah that's what I'm trying to figure out **recursive functions**, I've changed the title to be more relevant to that, what is `C`?

Comment: maybe also change "complexity of any algorithm" to "any **recursive** algorithm"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time complexity of many recursive algorithms can be expressed in terms of itself, just like the algorithm. This is called a *recurrence relation*, and is typically of the format

`T(N) = [sum of T(N_i) for recursive call i] + [sum of other work done in the function]`

For example, binary search has a very simple recurrence relation: for each recursive call 1) the search space is halved, and 2) a constant amount of work is done. Thus the relation is of the form `T(N) = T(N / 2) + C`. To solve this, repeatedly substitute it and spot a pattern:

```
T(N) = T(N / (2^1)) + C
     = T(N / (2^2)) + 2C
     = T(N / (2^3)) + 3C
     = ... 
     = T(N / (2^m)) + mC
```

Binary search terminates when the search space is just one element, i.e. when `N / (2^m) = 1`. This corresponds to `m = log2(N)`, and `T(N / (2^m)) = 0`.

Thus the time complexity is `O(m) = O(log N)`. (The base of the log does not matter and neither does `C`, since they are both multiplicative constants)

Answer (score 0):

For most common recurrence relations, your answer is the Master Theorem. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

You will also find this explained in CRLS - Introduction to Algorithms.